# Remove the Rupee symbol in Laravel

Tags: html, excel, laravel

I should see the rupee symbol on my webpage for the column.

Invoice page:
[image]

When I Download it through an Excel file the rupee symbol should be removed it should look like this

Downloaded file:
[image]

How do I do that?

Comment: what have you tried ? what issues did you encounter in your tries ? how is your data formatted ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have tried using str replace and preg replace it not working. its in string

Comment: did you read the topic "how to ask" ? I asked what have you tried **code wise** and edit your question and add the code you tried and explain the issues you encountered.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways you can approach this, however, I presume that "export to excel"
function is some kind of front-end library like DataTables?

If this is the case then you need to catch the data before the export function. This is from the DataTables.

Example:

```
var export_data = table.buttons.exportData({
    format: {
      body: removeRupee
    }
  }); 

function removeRupee(data, columnIndex){   
  return ((columnIndex === 2 || columnIndex ===4) ? data.slice(0, -1) : data)   

}
```

If the export is generated from the backend, then I suggest you don't keep the currency in the same column as value.